# call the external java selenium method in between execution of test complete jscript

Tags: selenium, testing, automation, ui-automation, testcomplete

I need to run my `selenium script` from maven project in between the test complete `jscript` execution.

How do I call the external java selenium method in between execution of test complete `j_script`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Event Handler](https://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/75628/) to perform actions before/after a test is run (OnStartTest/OnStopTest).

Once you've [added your Selenium test to TestComplete](https://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/72389/) you can [execute them](https://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/72404/#ID0EPC) e.g. from script-

```
SeleniumTests.JUnitTest1.Execute();
```